# SQL query on 3 pieces of info dependent on 1 another in 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an issue with a SQL Server 2008 database with 3 tables: `TradeAllocations`, `TradeTickets` and `Contracts`.

I want ALL `Trade Allocations` for ALL `Contracts` that have prompt dates > today in `Trade Tickets`. Any subquery and joins I tried resulted in no data, or only future prompt dates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
SELECT 
    TA.ContractID_Ref, C.Contract_Num, TT.PromptDate
FROM 
    TradeAllocations as TA
JOIN
    Contracts as C ON C.ContractID = TA.ContractID_Ref
JOIN 
    TradeTickets as TT ON TT.TradeTicketID = TA.TradeTicketID_Ref
```

Comment: You don't appear to be checking the date anywhere.  Why would you expect your results to be filtered by date?

Comment: "prompt dates > today" is another way of saying "future prompt dates."  Perhaps you want to reverse the inequality?

Comment: Thank you!  I did try WHERE TT.PromptDates > GETDATE() - but that only brings future prompt dates, and not previous prompt dates related to the Trade Allocations.  I'm trying to get ALL Trade Allocations linked to Contracts within Trade Tickets where Prompt Date is greater than today

Answer (score 0):

You have given us very little to go off of, but I will take a shot.  Try adding a where clause to your query:

```
SELECT TA.ContractID_Ref, C.Contract_Num, TT.PromptDate
FROM TradeAllocations as TA
INNER JOIN Contracts as C
   ON C.ContractID = TA.ContractID_Ref
INNER JOIN TradeTickets as TT
   ON TT.TradeTicketID = TA.TradeTicketID_Ref
WHERE TT.PromptDates > GETDATE ()
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did try WHERE TT.PromptDates > GETDATE() - but that only brings future prompt dates, and not previous prompt dates related to the Trade Allocations. I'm trying to get ALL Trade Allocations linked to Contracts within Trade Tickets where Prompt Date is greater than today

Comment: It sounds like you want all `PromptDates` that are less than today's date....  Try changing `>` to `<`

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, but only for Contracts that do have Current Trade Allocations (ie Contracts Containing Trade Allocations with Future Prompt Date)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Trades (Table 1) have many Trade Allocations (Table 2) all relating to Contracts (Table 3) - Prompt Dates are only in Table 3, and I want ALL Contracts that have Prompt Dates in the future including old Prompt Dates.  Sorry for making it more confusing - hope this is clearer?